# How to use "change event" in bootstrap-wysiwyg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I am using the bootstrap-wysiwyg.

I need an event to occur after text is modified and the input box is blurred.

I saw the below code, but this isn't the event I want

```
 // bind the event event
 $('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('document').keypress(function(e) {

 // This will cancel the keypress
 e.preventDefault();

 // alert
 alert('Keypress detected!');
 });
```

I want an event to occur after text is modified and the input box is blurred.

Event I want is similar to ".change()" in jQuery.

I hope you help me.. thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a question is a bit old, but here's how you can do it in case you still need to solve this issue in the future. Assuming that you're using the latest version of bootstrap-wysiwyg you can do what you're wanting using the following code:

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg().on('change', function()
{
    // You code goes here
});
```

You can download the latest version from [here](https://github.com/steveathon/bootstrap-wysiwyg/releases).